# Discord bot error handling doesn't allow me to pass 3 arguments

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, discord.py

I am unable to pass 3 arguments (self, error, ctx) to my error handler shown bellow every time I try whatever argument I pass last comes back as a missing argument.

```html
@bot.command(name='dice')
async def dice(ctx, number_of_dice: int, number_of_sides: int):
    dice = [
        str(random.choice(range(1, number_of_sides + 1)))
        for x in range(number_of_dice)
        ]
    await ctx.send(', '.join(dice))


@dice.error
async def dice_handler(self, error, ctx):
    message = (
        'the dice command needs the number of dice and the number of sides'
        ' to run. \n Example: dice 1 20\n will roll 1 dice with 20 sides')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        if error.param.name == "number_of_dice":
            await ctx.send(message)
        elif error.param.name == "number_of_sides":
            await ctx.send(message)
```

this is the output i receive.

```
Irresistible Bot has connected to discord!
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: number_of_dice is a required argument that is missing.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 71, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: dice_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 976, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 943, in invoke
    await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 424, in dispatch_error
    await injected(ctx, error)
  File "C:\Users\kit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 77, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: dice_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out i did not need to use self because I am not using cog.

Answer (score 0):

`self` parameter is just for cogs. You aren't using cogs so, `dice_handler` takes only `context` and `error` parameters.